# Dynamic setting of html options of a select box does not appear in select html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We can dynamically mark some options with `jquery`

With below select:

```
<select name='strings' id="strings" multiple style="width:100px;">
    <option value="Test">Test</option>
    <option value="Prof">Prof</option>
    <option value="Live">Live</option>
    <option value="Off">Off</option>
    <option value="On">On</option>
</select>
```

The below `js` will select `Test,Prof,Off`

```
var values="Test,Prof,Off";
$.each(values.split(","), function(i,e){
    $("#strings option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
});

console.log( $("#strings").html() );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3f0ea4dc/

This works fine ...

But the `$("#strings").html()` does not mark options as selected. So I expected to see

```
  <option value="Test" selected>Test</option>
```

But I see

```
  <option value="Test">Test</option>.
```

Any comments ?! Is there any way I can get the html with selected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `prop()` by `attr()` it will work as expected ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code :-

```
$.each(values.split(","), function(i,e){
    $("#strings option[value='" + e + "']").attr("selected", true);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3f0ea4dc/3/